# JNLP read file permission

Tags: java, security, jnlp, accesscontrolexception

My problem is that program cannot read file (I also don't see pop-up permission window when it's loading!)
It's a JNLP file, in it I got (but still I don't see any pop-ups):

```html
<security>
    <all-permissions/>
< /security>
```

when I execute that file it download some data and run normaly but when I try to load file I get an error:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" (...) )
```

I tried to give permision through java system setting and I also tried to change policy files but still it doesnt work.

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).

Comment: BTW - `< /security>` should be `</security>`